# Content Organizer not working

Tags: content-organizer

I have setup up a default "Content Organizer" with one "Drop off library" and one "Document library".
When i upload a document to the "Drop off library", and press "Submit", i get an exception.

From the ULS-logs i found the following:

```
CITPList::SetValue failed.
CITPList::SetValue failed with hr 0x80070057 for fieldid {BC1A8EFB-0F4C-49F8-A38F- 7FE22AF3D3E0}
Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.
```

Field-ID "BC1A8EFB-0F4C-49F8-A38F- 7FE22AF3D3E0" --> Source Version (Converted Document)

It seems, after routing the document to the document library, SP tries to update the field "Source Version" (ParentVersionString) and then an exception is thrown.

I don't know what i can do to resolve this problem.
Like i wrote at the beginning, everthing is OOTB, no customizing.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SP2016 + patch from March 2023